# Gap in understanding angular

Tags: angularjs

Trying to learn angular. There's something that seems like a paradox to me. When it comes to angular routing, you can have something like this:

```
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })
```

when you enter "domain.com/about" manually -- won't the whole page just reload from the server? Isn't angular supposed to prevent that and just re-load the about.html into the right position? If this indeed happens-- I don't understand how angular prevents the web browser from just downloading the whole page all over again when the user manually goes to the address bar and changes it to "domain.com/about".

Comment: have you tried this to see what happens?

Comment: if you aren't using hash in url server needs to be configured to recognize the virtual directories you are using and always deliver the app entry point page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't prevent the user from using a browser as it's intended to be used, and why should it?

It isn't just Angular that exemplifies a behavior where the browser is allowed to do what the browser is allowed to do.  This has been the case for any Single Page App built on any framework, whether that framework be jQuery, Knockout, Ember, etc.

All Angular does with its routing is ensure that each route corresponds to a unique location in the app.  At that point it us up to **YOU**, the developer, to ensure an idempotent load where the user never experiences complete disruption and can always pick up their work, regardless of whether or not they completely reloaded the application.

Comment: So basically if I have a /Page2 routing in Angular ....  I need to have a "/Page2" supported in the routes.php of my PHP application -- which will bring (only) the content that's required for injection into where the angular "/page2? content goes on my page?

Comment: I can't speak to what your routes.php is doing, but that doesn't sound quite right.  When using routing, you are creating a single page application.  In the PHP world, you would typically load up an index.php file that includes all of your javascript dependencies.  At that point, you'd allow routing to determine what templates and controllers to load based on where you are at.  However, that is a different question from what you've asked above.  If you still have questions around how to make that work, I recommend a new question with a short, complete example that describes what you need.

Comment: Are you saying PHP cannot be used as a backend for an Angular.js application?

Comment: sounds totally wrong actually. php shouldn't have the same routes as angular if you are using `html5Mode` in angular routing. If you aren't setting `html5Mode` use the hash in your url's

Comment: Forget PHP for a second. When angular routes to "/Page2". isn't a request being made to the web server to obtain "domain.com/Page2"?

Comment: It calls the server to obtain whatever you tell it to in your routing: templateUrl : 'pages/page2.html',
        controller  : 'page2Controller'.  The **routing** controls what is loaded , when.

Comment: If I can add @RM1970, why do you expect it not to load the entire page? The example you showed did not show nested views so of course it needs to load the whole page if you type it in from scratch..